# ISNUMERIC function with Tab char(9)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was working with ISNUMERIC function in SQL Server, when I encountered a strange trouble.

Check text including below characters ISNUMERIC function return 1(true). Why?

```
Tab char(9)
Line feed char(10)
Carriage return char(13)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only Char(9),it does for all of the values below..

```
SELECT [Ascii Code]        = STR(Number),
        [Ascii Character]   = CHAR(Number),
        [ISNUMERIC Returns] = ISNUMERIC(CHAR(Number))
   FROM Master.dbo.spt_Values
  WHERE Type = 'P'
    AND Number BETWEEN 0 AND 255
    AND ISNUMERIC(CHAR(Number)) = 1

Ascii Code Ascii Character ISNUMERIC Returns 
---------- --------------- ----------------- 
         9                 1
        10                 1
        11                 1
        12                 1
        13                 1
        36 $               1
        43 +               1
        44 ,               1
        45 -               1
        46 .               1
        48 0               1
        49 1               1
        50 2               1
        51 3               1
        52 4               1
        53 5               1
        54 6               1
```

From the Official docs..emphasis on highlighted..

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression **evaluates to a valid integer, floating point number, money or decimal type**; otherwise it returns 0. A return value of 1 guarantees that expression can be converted to one of these numeric types

So Isnumeric will return 1 if it returns any one of the type in highlighted part above..

Jeff moden Describes the why part [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/)..

> There are many different combinations of letters, numbers, and symbols that can actually be converted to numeric data types and ISNUMERIC will return a "1" for all of them. It's not a flaw... that's the way it's supposed to work!

References:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/

Comment: Thanks for response.